# Images push all the other columns to the side?

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

I'm having problems with addings images to a grid layout. Im trying to learn how to work with a grid, and I have all the columns and rows how I want them to, but when I add an image it doesn't fit as it should! It pushes all the other colomns away. 
What am I doing wrong? Sorry that the code isn't in the shorthand version yet, im learning it by writing everything out first so Im 100% understand what i'm typing. When everything is right I make it shorter, its kind of a learning process! ;)   got the template from W3.

```css
.main {
  max-height:90vh;
}

.item1 { grid-column: 1 / span 11; }
.item2 { grid-column: 12 / span 2 ; }
.item3 { grid-column: 14/ span 11 ; }
.item4 { grid-column: 1 / span 6;}
.item5 { grid-column: 7 / span 6 ; }
.item6 { grid-column: 13 / span 6 ;  }
.item7 { grid-column: 19 / span 6; }
.item8 {grid-column: 1/ span 24;}


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 15vh 75vh 10vh;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#leftheader {
  width:30%;
  align-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>websiteportfolio</title>
<link href="indexcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">

 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1"> <img src="text\ellis.png" id="leftheader" alt="Ellis"> </div>
  <div class="item2">2 </div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
 <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
 <div class="item7">7</div>
 <div class="item8">8</div>
</div>
  </div>
   </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Could you add a fully qualified path to the image? It's not showing up in your example.

Comment: The issue with `grid-column` is that it will always recalculate the space it takes based on inner content of other divs. Saying `.item1` will `grid-column: 1 / span 11` doesn't necessarily mean it will take exact "eleven spaces"  in your grid, but that, in the general grid, it will span 11 cols depending on what the other grids are spanning. Try writing a long text in the `item1` [in this example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-column)  and see how the other divs will get smaller.

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all. You currently have `grid-template-columns` set to have 24 different columns.

Comment: Aha ok!  I think in that case I will just start over. I read somewhere that you should do a 12 column grid or a 24 column grid so you would have more control over the page. Turns out that's wrong hah, oops. Thanks Major Sam for the good answer, I understand! :)